# how to generate cron expression through millisecond..?

Tags: windows

I need to generate the cron expression based on milliseconds. For example: what will be the cron expression for 86400(milliseconds) and how to get the expression..? Please help..

Thanks...

Comment: 86400 is the number of seconds in a day. It has nothing to do with milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

`cron` is not intended for high-accuracy timing ! Forget about seconds or even milliseconds precision here. The best you can get is minutes.

`cron` **CAN be and is frequently off** by several seconds (due to process start-up, ...).

If you really require that kind of precision, you should build your own daemon (unless I got your question wrong).

---

If your intend is "just" to convert second/millisecond time to crontab expression.
Then:

- I assume these jobs are daily jobs, that is `<second_number>` **<** 84600
- 1st arg = minutes of the hour = `int( (<second_number> % 3600) / 60)`
- 2nd arg = hours of the day  = `int( (<second_number> / 3600) )`
- 3rd arg = every day of the month = *
- 4th arg = every month of the year = *
- 5th arg = every day of the week  = *

For more have look at the [crontab man page](http://www2.themanualpage.org/unix/cron.php3).

Comment: my concern is.. i have a table containing trigger timings for different jobs.. i need to get the cron expression for those triggers from that table.. but that table contains a column which has time in seconds/millisecond(86400).. so cant we get cron expression for the trigger based on particular column containing timings..?